# How to create an echo device in Linux?

Tags: linux, bash, sh, hp-ux

I'm working on porting this bash script over to Linux from HP-UX.  There appears to be a command

```
remsh opcfdp01 "find  ${TOOLS_DIR} -user ${ADMIN_USER} -exec chmod a+rwx {} \;"  < /dev/echo > /dev/null 2>&1
```

The device file `/dev/echo` appears to print the output on HP-UX; however, no such file seems to exist in Linux.

I was wondering how I could go about creating a `/dev/echo` in Linux.

Comment: The example you posted makes very little sense.  Can you provide some context as to what you are trying to actually do with it?  Like a use case maybe.

Comment: Could you explain what `/dev/echo` does? I can't find any understandable info on this. It "prints the output" of what?

Comment: @ormaaj: I think what it does is print the output from any command to the device file /dev/echo and then echo it back to stdout.

Comment: The most simliar thing you can use is a named pipe. Just do a `mkpipe`. It do have some different, you have to check the blocking status.

Answer (score 1):

The **[`remsh`](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=remsh&manpath=HP-UX+11.22)** command is like "rsh".  It is executing a `find` command on the remote host 'opcfdp01'.  The command line you posted has `remsh` getting its stdin from `/dev/echo`, which I believe you should not require.

As far as I was aware, the `/dev/echo` device is only used by **[`strvf`](http://nixdoc.net/man-pages/hp-ux/man1/strvf.1m.html)** in HP/UX.

There is also some discussion on this at [openss7.org](http://www.openss7.org/man2html?4+echo)

You may be able to get away with simple removing the `< /dev/echo` part of the commandline altogether, especially if you don't know whether you're using `strvf` and you're changing your script to use `ssh` instead of `remsh`.